# replace string with python, but only when it is respecting conditions

Tags: python

I have the following string :

```
HELLO (IS_POLITE{{HI HELLO}}; HELLO; AAA, HELLO HELLO IS_POLITE{{HELLO}})
```

With python , i need to replace the word HELLO by "TEST" but not when it is between IS_POLITE{{ }}.

my output is :

```
TEST (IS_POLITE{{HI HELLO}}; TEST; AAA, TEST TEST IS_POLITE{{HELLO}})
```

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach uses `re.sub` with a callback function:

```py
def repl(m):
    match = m.group(0)
    if match == 'HELLO':
        return 'TEST'
    else:
        return match

inp = "HELLO (IS_POLITE{{HI HELLO}}; HELLO; AAA, HELLO HELLO IS_POLITE{{HELLO}})"
output = re.sub(r'IS_POLITE\{\{.*?\}\}|\bHELLO\b', repl, inp)
print(output)
```

This prints:

```
TEST (IS_POLITE{{HI HELLO}}; TEST; AAA, TEST TEST IS_POLITE{{HELLO}})
```

The regex alternation will first try to find `IS_POLITE{{<anything>}}`, which we want to spare from replacement, only matching `HELLO` in all other cases.  Then, in the callback function, we selectively replace `HELLO` with `TEST` only in the latter case.

Comment: what is "contents ", it does not compile

Comment: @vlad Reload your page, I had a typo in there (which was quickly fixed).

Comment: it gives that :TEST (IS_POLITE{{HI TEST}}; TEST; AAA, TEST TEST IS_POLITE{{HELLO}})   the first hello is modofied

Comment: Sorry, I missed that requirement.

Comment: is there a way to make the HELLO and TEST as parameters : def repl(m):
    match = m.group(0)
    if match == param1:
        return param2
    else:
        return match

Comment: Use the one-liner version: `re.sub(r'IS_POLITE\{\{.*?\}\}|\bHELLO\b', lambda x: param2 if x.group(0) == param1 else x.group(), inp)`